Firefox misnumbers reversed ordered list if counter-reset is used elsewhere
Try the snippet below on Firefox (128.0.3 at the time of writing). The reversed <ol> list will start at 5. Firefox seems to be counting the number of items in the other list, for which a counter-reset is used, with any name. Try adding or deleting items to the <ul> list to see the effect.
Workaround: if you can use counter-set, then the problem does not occur.


ul {
  counter-reset: whatever;
}
<ol reversed>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>One</li>
</ol>

<ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
</ul>




I observe the same behavior.
